# Xcode: resolving include

Tags: c++, xcode

I have some C++ project and I tried to create project as "External Build System". I added files to the project via right click on project > "Add files to ...".

First, compiler can't find  `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` even I installed it by macports and added path /opt/local/include/ in the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS (Build Settings).

Second, Xcode doesn't see local headers of the project: I see both "A.cpp" and "A.h" in the source tree, but Xcode says "Symbol not found" when I ⌘ +  click on the include like `#include "A.h"`.

What's wrong with my project settings?

Comment: "Symbol not found" is generally a linker error, not a compiler error arising out of missing headers. Have you added `-lboost` to the linker flags?

Comment: Well, if you mean OTHER_LDFLAGS, it doesn't work with `-lboost` too. In the logs I see calling g++ without `-I/opt/local/include/`, by the way.